# no such file or directory: #/usr/bin/perl

Tags: perl

I am super new to Perl and really struggling to even get started on my local computer. I have success using other computers but would like to start working on my own laptop. Using my Mac terminal, I am attempting to use the shebang line, and it is finding no such file or directory. Below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

In return, I get:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
zsh: no such file or directory: #/usr/bin/perl
```

I know this is basic, but I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Execute `which perl` command where the Perl is located. Usually it will be in `/usr/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand how you write "I want to use my shebang line".

Typicaly you would write a file with a text editor, and it would *contain* a shebang line. And the shebang would contain the # and the ! (bang). So for instance, create a file called `hello.pl` with this contents:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Hello World!\n";
```

Then if you would make the file executable, and execute it, the shell will run it using the interpreter you specified in the shebang. So in your shell:

```
$ chmod +x hello.pl
$ ./hello.pl
Hello World!
$
```

Please note that you can also *not* have a shebang, and still execute the file like this:

```
$ perl hello.pl
Hello World!
$
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, you don't have the bang in your shebang: `#/usr/bin/perl`.

Did you type in your program or cut and paste? Re-tying often corrects errors that we don't notice.